# rails .today? evaluating in UTC instead of timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I want to display "Today" when a meeting_time is today. meeting_time is saved in UTC, and then converted to the local timezone:

```
<% meeting_time = meeting.meeting_time.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)") %>
```

`<% meeting_time.today? %>` evaluates to true at 7pm the day before, because 'today?' is a UTC time I believe.

How can I use the 'today' method in a different timezone?
I have already tried:

```
<% meeting_time.today.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")? %>
```

but this throws an error.

Thanks!

Comment: set the time zone first using `Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` before calling `meeting_time.today?`

Comment: @jvnill wow that is so straight forward I feel dumb... can you please post as answer below so I can accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the timezone first using `Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` before calling `meeting_time.today?`.  Be warned though that this sets the timezone application wide.  You usually just do this in the config files.

**UPDATE**

Use `Time.use_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')` for your needs.

```
Time.use_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)') do
  meeting_time.today?
end
```

Comment: How can I not set it throughout the app? I just want to compare the time in this one controller. Thanks!